# How can these arrays be the same?

Tags: actionscript-3

```
var oldArray:Array = new Array("a", "o", "a", "o", "a", "o", "a", "o");

      for (var i:int = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {


    if (i % 2 == 0) {
    trace("go to array 1 " + i);
    applesArray.push(oldArray[i]);
    }

    if (i % 2 != 0) {
    trace("go to array 2 " + i);
    orangesArray.push(oldArray[i]);
    } 

}
```

those first two traces come out as I expect but then if I trace oneArray and twoArray they come out the same.

trace(applesArray);
trace(orangesArray);

How can they be the same?

Comment: How are `applesArray` and `orangesArray` declared?

Comment: Add `oldArray[i]` into the trace statement for "go to array 1" or 2, perhaps you don't get what's expected out of `oldArray`. `trace("go to array 1", i, oldArray[i]);`

Comment: also it would be 1000times quicker to find a solution if you would post also the output of your traces

Answer (score 2):

I was only able to reproduce "error" with this code:

```
var oldArray:Array = new Array("a", "o", "a", "o", "a", "o", "a", "o");
var applesArray:Array;
var orangesArray:Array;
applesArray = orangesArray = [];//this makes it invalid
      for (var i:int = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {


    if (i % 2 == 0) {
    trace("go to array 1 " + i);
    applesArray.push(oldArray[i]);
    }

    if (i % 2 != 0) {
    trace("go to array 2 " + i);
    orangesArray.push(oldArray[i]);
    } 
}           
trace(applesArray);
trace(orangesArray);

//traces output
go to array 1 0
go to array 2 1
go to array 1 2
go to array 2 3
go to array 1 4
go to array 2 5
go to array 1 6
go to array 2 7
a,o,a,o,a,o,a,o
a,o,a,o,a,o,a,o
```

if it is what you have done then you have to remember that Array is not primitive object like a number which is passed by  value, arrays like other complex objects are passed by reference and your both variables pointed to the same object.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.  I didn't know you can't assign another array to an array.

Comment: You can, but it will assign reference to object not copy of that object:)